# NodeJs express-validator - Validate nested object

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am using express-validator(6.x) version to validate input request params.

I have an address nested object, So this field is optional but if have address key other nested objects are mandatory.

Sample input

```
const details = {
  name: "abcd",
  address: {
    area: "test1",
    city: {
      code: "123",
      name: "test"
    },
    state: {
      code: "123",
      name: "test"
    },
    country: {
      code: "123",
      name: "test"
    } 
  }
}

const validate = [
  body('name').not().isEmpty().isString(),
  body('address.area').optional().isString(),
  body('address.city.name').optional().isString(),
  body('address.city.code').optional().isString(),
  body('address.state.name').optional().isString(),
  body('address.state.code').optional().isString(),
  body('address.country.code').optional().isString(),
  body('address.country.name').optional().isString(),
]

router.route('/:userId')
  .put(update, function(req, res){
    //code.... 
  })
```

Here, I tried to use a custom key but not working.

Sample input#1 (Valid)

```
const details = {
  name: "abcd"
}
```

Sample Input#2:

```
const details = {
  name: "abcd",
  address: {}
}
```

The above input is invalid and should have all address nested objects like area,state,country..

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a custom validator that checks the condition when address value is present, like below

```
const validate = [
  body('name').not().isEmpty().isString(),
  body('address').optional(),
  body('address.city.name').custom((value,{req}) => {
    if(req.body.address != undefined && req.body.address.city.name == undefined){
       throw new Error("City is required for the address");
    }
    else {
      return true;
    }
  })
];
```

Comment: add similar custom validators for the other fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer., I tried this one but expecting any other solutions